# How to use grep to filter out words like food and foot but not liked foody or footed

Tags: bash, grep

Hey People so I know what I want to do which would be to use the grep command to filter out words like foot, food, fool from a dictionary file but still retain words like footed and foodilicous.

so this is the code I have so far

```
cat /home1/02836/sulstice/dictionary.txt | grep -E foo | grep -vE '^foo'
```

The cat command is just pulling the dictionary txt which is just a bunch of words.

The last command I feel like there would be something I can put to say ^foo(if there is a character and end of the word then omit that too).

There must be a way using the grep function, anyone got a way?

Thank you

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

With Gnu grep, you can use the `-w` flag to restrict the match to full words, so:

```
grep -w foo[[:alpha:]] /home1/02836/sulstice/dictionary.txt
```

will match full words which consist of `foo` plus one letter.

Note that there is no need for `cat`. You can tell grep which file(s) to search in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that dictionary.txt has a single word per line then you should be able to just use ^foo$